# Property 'id' does not exist on type 'any[]'

Tags: angular

everything works fine but it gives me this error in git.
editeur code stresses on id `response.id;`.

```
  create(){
    this.postService.create(this.post)
    .subscribe(
      (response:any[])=>{
         this.post.id=response.id;
         this.posts.unshift(this.post);
         this.post={
          id:0,
          title:'',
          body:'',
          userId:''
        }        
    },(error:AppError)=>{
      if(error instanceof BadInput){
        alert('c post deja supprimer')
      }else{
        alert('error inattendue')
      }
    }
    )
  }
```

Comment: Why would you expect there be a property named `id` on an array of type `any`?

Comment: Add a debugger statement and then look at developer tools in the browser to see the value of response object. This will give you an idea of what's going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check first response contains id property if exist then try bellow code.

```
create(){
    this.postService.create(this.post)
    .subscribe(
      (response:any)=>{
         this.post.id=response.id;
         this.posts.unshift(this.post);
         this.post={
          id:0,
          title:'',
          body:'',
          userId:''
        }        
    },(error:AppError)=>{
      if(error instanceof BadInput){
        alert('c post deja supprimer')
      }else{
        alert('error inattendue')
      }
    }
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are reading the response as an array, you cannot use any property of an array without any index value.

Could you please use like below and put the debugger at line this.post=response to check the response and share the response here, so that I can help you with the exact fix.

create(){
    this.postService.create(this.post)
    .subscribe(
      (response)=>{
         this.post=response;
      }) ;
 }